# Is Equals(Object,Guid.Empty) The Same as Object == Guid.Empty

Tags: c#

Is the result of the following code line of code:

```
if (Equals(comp.Id, Guid.Empty)) return;
```

always the same as the next line of code?

```
if(comp.Id == Guid.Empty) return;
```

Comment: [Source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) is your friend.

Comment: Your code doesn't give the definition of `Equals`  or if `==` is an overloaded operator, so we cannot tell you.

Comment: @Dai Both are from the BCL: [`object.Equals(object, object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k) and [overloaded `operator ==` for `Guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.op_equality).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The default implementation of both checks for reference in a reference type, and checks actual content for a value type.
2. Not necessarily, both == and .Equals can be overloaded.
3. Guid and string both override both == and .Equals, and the implementations are the same, checking for equality between two Guids is value based, and comparison between two strings will be value based as well.  Comparing strings and Guids, however, will always return false regardless of how you do it.  You'll need to either compare the result of Guid.ToString() with the string value, or you'll need to convert the string to a Guid.

taken from 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a505b091-9166-4c74-91dd-a8e9eb6ad001/-and-equals-comparision-for-systemguid-and-string?forum=csharplanguage

I dont think you should assume that, if your Equals method looks like this

```
Equals(guid id1, guid id2)
{
   return id1 == id2 ;
}
```

i hope this makes sense..... equals needs context

if equals looks like this....

```
equsl(guid id1, guid id2)
{
   string firstG = id1.toString();
   string secondG = id2.toString();
   return firstG == secondG;
}
```

here you can see it would be a string comparison not a guid comparison ... it could come out different ....

Comment: What makes you think `string` is relevant here?

Comment: @svick The `Equals` in the question has no class or namespace name, so for all we know it is defined by the user.  I think he was just pointing out that if it is user-defined then our answers won't be very helpful without seeing the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is going to assume that `comp.Id` is a `Guid` and that you didn't do anything unusual, like have a custom overload of `Equals()` with two parameters or use custom `Guid` type different from `System.Guid`.

Your first line will call [the static method `object.Equals(object objA, object objB)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k). What that method does is to check for `null` (not relevant here, since `Guid`s can never be `null`) and then call `objA.Equals(objB)`. Since `Guid` [overrides `object.Equals(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57t2t4e3), that's the method that's going to be called. And that method compares the two `Guid` values for equality (assuming the parameter indeed is `Guid`, which it is here).

Your second line will call [the overloaded `operator ==` for `Guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.op_equality). That again compares the two `Guid`s for equality.

This means that the methods will have the same result. The main difference is that the first line works with `object`s, which means both your `Guid`s have to be boxed. And doing that can negatively affect performance. So in this case, I would suggest using `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the source [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/guid.cs), here are the source codes for both functions (assuming `comp.ID` is a `Guid`, your `Equals` is `Guid.Equals` and neither has been overloaded, of course).  It appears both function in exactly the same way.

```
    public bool Equals(Guid g)
    {
        // Now compare each of the elements
        if(g._a != _a)
            return false;
        if(g._b != _b)
            return false;
        if(g._c != _c)
            return false;
        if (g._d != _d)
            return false;
        if (g._e != _e)
            return false;
        if (g._f != _f)
            return false;
        if (g._g != _g)
            return false;
        if (g._h != _h)
            return false;
        if (g._i != _i)
            return false;
        if (g._j != _j)
            return false;
        if (g._k != _k)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

 public static bool operator ==(Guid a, Guid b)
    {
        // Now compare each of the elements
        if(a._a != b._a)
            return false;
        if(a._b != b._b)
            return false;
        if(a._c != b._c)
            return false;
        if(a._d != b._d)
            return false;
        if(a._e != b._e)
            return false;
        if(a._f != b._f)
            return false;
        if(a._g != b._g)
            return false;
        if(a._h != b._h)
            return false;
        if(a._i != b._i)
            return false;
        if(a._j != b._j)
            return false;
        if(a._k != b._k)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

EDIT:  If you are using the `object.Equals` method linked by svick, the last line states the following:

If the two objects do not represent the same object reference and neither is null, it calls objA.Equals(objB) and returns the result. This means that if objA overrides the Object.Equals(Object) method, this override is called.

`Guid` does have an overload for `Equals(object)`, so let's take a look at the source:

```
public override bool Equals(Object o)
    {
        Guid g;
        // Check that o is a Guid first
        if(o == null || !(o is Guid))
            return false;
        else g = (Guid) o;

        // Now compare each of the elements
        if(g._a != _a)
            return false;
        if(g._b != _b)
            return false;
        if(g._c != _c)
            return false;
        if (g._d != _d)
            return false;
        if (g._e != _e)
            return false;
        if (g._f != _f)
            return false;
        if (g._g != _g)
            return false;
        if (g._h != _h)
            return false;
        if (g._i != _i)
            return false;
        if (g._j != _j)
            return false;
        if (g._k != _k)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

As we can see, this function checks that the passed object is in fact a `Guid` (which would simply not work with `Guid`'s overload of `==`, so it's a moot point) and then does the same thing as `Equals(Guid)` (in fact, it appears the implementation was copied since even the comment is the same and doesn't quite fit in `Equals(Guid)`).

So, the ultimate answer appears to be that assuming both objects are `Guids`, the only instance where `Equals` returns a different result than `operator==` is when both objects are null: the former will return true while the latter will (I think) throw a null reference exception.

Comment: How can `Equals` be `Guid.Equals`? That doesn't have an overload that takes two parameters. I think it's pretty clear it's [`object.Equals(object, object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k).